# Firebase Admin SDK not updating password as expected

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm using cloud functions, and I'm trying to manually override a users password (I also have password email resets set up also).

I can successfully update a user number, enable / disabled status etc however when passing the password variable it seems to fail, with no error message.

The password must be a 'raw, unhashed password. Must be at least six characters long.'

Following the documentation, my cloud function is as follows.

```
exports.resetUserPassword = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  if (!context.auth.token.superadmin) return

  try {
    console.log(data.password)
    admin.auth().updateUser(data.uid, {
      password: 'testpassword',
    })
      .then(function(userRecord) {
        // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
        console.log("Successfully updated user", userRecord.toJSON());
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error updating user:", error);
      });

    return true
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

});
```

When I look at the logs for the firebase function, the response seems to indicate the password hasn't been updated (and certainly when I try to log in with the test account the password has been set to something...IDK....). Note that  passwordHash and passwordSalt are undefined,

```
Successfully updated user { uid: 'HMxo5NcObYTN5LPsgSb0ZTCK6213',
  email: 'test@test.com',
  emailVerified: false,
  displayName: undefined,
  photoURL: undefined,
  phoneNumber: undefined,
  disabled: false,
  metadata: 
   { lastSignInTime: 'Tue, 19 May 2020 00:36:16 GMT',
     creationTime: 'Tue, 19 May 2020 00:36:16 GMT' },
  passwordHash: undefined,
  passwordSalt: undefined,
  customClaims: { customer: true },
  tokensValidAfterTime: 'Tue, 19 May 2020 13:50:02 GMT',
  tenantId: undefined,
  providerData: 
   [ { uid: 'test@test.com',
       displayName: undefined,
       email: 'test@test.com',
       photoURL: undefined,
       providerId: 'password',
       phoneNumber: undefined } ] }
```

Comment: It is not clear for me if you encounter an error or not. You write "it seems to fail, with no error message.", then you mention what seems to be an error message "The password must be a 'raw, unhashed password. Must be at least six characters long." then you say "certainly when I try to log in with the test account the password has been set to something"? So what is your exact problem, please?

Comment: That's not an error message, is reference to the documentation. There is no error thrown when running this but the password remains unchanged

Comment: Sorry gets changed to an unknown valus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ignoring the promise returned by `updateUser().then().catch()`.  Callable functions need to return a promise that resolves with the response to send to the caller, after all the async work has finished.  Right now, your function returns just `true` and completes immediately, before the work of `updateUser` actually finishes.

In order to allow the work to complete, you should return the promise chain, and indicate what the caller is supposed to receive:

```
return admin.auth().updateUser(...)
.then(() => {
    return "whatever you want the client to receive on success"
})
.catch(error => {
    return "whatever you want the client to receive on error"
})
```

Comment: this did not work for me. I have tried calling `updateUser` in a node shell, and have observed that it correctly updates fields such as `displayName` but the `passwordHash` and `passwordSalt` fields remain as undefined